# Ionic native deeplink not route to specific page

Tags: ionic3

I using ionic native Deeplinks plugin and the code below:

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {Platform, Nav, ionicBootstrap} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Deeplinks} from 'ionic-native';

import {AboutPage} from './pages/about/about';
import {HatDetailPage} from './pages/hat/hat';

@Component({
  template: '<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>',
})
class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav:Nav;

  constructor(private _platform: Platform) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this._platform.ready().then(() => {
      Deeplinks.routeWithNavController(this.nav, {
       '/about-us': AboutPage,
       '/hats/:hatId': HatDetailPage
      });
    });
  }
});
```

And i tested it , iy can open the app but not route me to the page, anyone have idea?

Comment: Why can't you use Ionic's default deep link feature?

Comment: Hi, Sampath. What do you means?

Comment: You can see that on this answer which I have provided.Please see it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45565895/1077309